# java - RestTemplate Exchange with target class as Nested Map and Lists

Tags: java, json, spring, resttemplate

I have a Rest Template exchange for get service. The service returns the responses as below :

**Response1(Single Document)**:-
    {
    "irpage": [{
        "drawer": "HPPS",
        "folderNumber": "HPA00008047642",
        "docID": "1",
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "din": "HPPSHPA00008047642000001",
        "userKey1": "20151119NJ",
        "docType": "APPD",
        "docDate": "20151119",
        "numberPages": "1",
        "fileName": "\12_HPPS\20151119\5_Z000\SCHEDL2\952490010845",
        "tempFileName": "\\prcins.net\Shared\irtestnjimages01\12_HPPS\20151119\5_Z000\SCHEDL2\952490010845.pdf",
        "driver": "",
        "dateCaptured": "20151119",
        "timeCaptured": "08:45:04",
        "singleInd": "S",
        "userID": "SCHEDL2",
        "status": "U",
        "batch": "Z000",
        "format": "PDF",
        "media": "D",
        "orientation": "0",
        "tempDin": "12201511190845952490845SCHEDL2",
        "transType": "APPD",
        "operator": "",
        "userkey2": "0",
        "reason": "Computer Generated Document",
        "archiveStatus": "A",
        "archiveDate": "20151119",
        "deviceID": "1",
        "packageID": "1",
        "packageType": "15007",
        "markedInd": "0",
        "dspPageNumber": "1",
        "aMedia": "",
        "aDrive": "",
        "description": "Output",
        "folderName": "GAIL BARTLING",
        "docDescription": "Application Document",
        "overlayID": null,
        "docIndex": null
    }]
}

**Response2(Multiple Documents)**: 
{
    "irpage": [{
        "drawer": "HPPS",
        "folderNumber": "HPA00008047642",
        "docID": "1",
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "din": "HPPSHPA00008047642000001",
        "userKey1": "20151119NJ",
        "docType": "APPD",
        "docDate": "20151119",
        "numberPages": "1",
        "fileName": "\12_HPPS\20151119\5_Z000\SCHEDL2\952490010845",
        "tempFileName": "\\prcins.net\Shared\irtestnjimages01\12_HPPS\20151119\5_Z000\SCHEDL2\952490010845.pdf",
        "driver": "",
        "dateCaptured": "20151119",
        "timeCaptured": "08:45:04",
        "singleInd": "S",
        "userID": "SCHEDL2",
        "status": "U",
        "batch": "Z000",
        "format": "PDF",
        "media": "D",
        "orientation": "0",
        "tempDin": "12201511190845952490845SCHEDL2",
        "transType": "APPD",
        "operator": "",
        "userkey2": "0",
        "reason": "Computer Generated Document",
        "archiveStatus": "A",
        "archiveDate": "20151119",
        "deviceID": "1",
        "packageID": "1",
        "packageType": "15007",
        "markedInd": "0",
        "dspPageNumber": "1",
        "aMedia": "",
        "aDrive": "",
        "description": "Output",
        "folderName": "GAIL BARTLING",
        "docDescription": "Application Document",
        "overlayID": null,
        "docIndex": null
    }, {
        "drawer": "HPPS",
        "folderNumber": "HPA00008047642",
        "docID": "4",
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "din": "HPPSHPA00008047642000004",
        "userKey1": "20160104NJ",
        "docType": "FINA",
        "docDate": "20160104",
        "numberPages": "1",
        "fileName": "\12_HPPS\20160105\5_Z000\SCHEDL2\308070010819",
        "tempFileName": "\\prcins.net\Shared\irtestnjimages01\12_HPPS\20160105\5_Z000\SCHEDL2\308070010819.pdf",
        "driver": "",
        "dateCaptured": "20160105",
        "timeCaptured": "08:19:30",
        "singleInd": "S",
        "userID": "SCHEDL2",
        "status": "U",
        "batch": "Z000",
        "format": "PDF",
        "media": "D",
        "orientation": "0",
        "tempDin": "12201601050819308070819SCHEDL2",
        "transType": "FINA",
        "operator": "",
        "userkey2": "0",
        "reason": "Computer Generated Document",
        "archiveStatus": "A",
        "archiveDate": "20160105",
        "deviceID": "1",
        "packageID": "4",
        "packageType": "15007",
        "markedInd": "0",
        "dspPageNumber": "1",
        "aMedia": "",
        "aDrive": "",
        "description": "Output",
        "folderName": "GAIL BARTLING",
        "docDescription": "Final Notice of Cancellation",
        "overlayID": null,
        "docIndex": null
    }]
}

When I provide the **Class < E > targetClass** as 
    **new HashMap< String, List< Map < String , String>>>().getClass()**
 the Response2 get parsed and I get the results in a Map, however the response1(Single Document) doesn't work and returns as null.

or If I provide the **Class < E > targetClass** as **new HashMap< String ,  Map < String, String>>().getClass()** the Response1 get parsed and I get the results in a Map, however the response2(Multiple Documents) doesn't work and returns as null.

I am not sure how to handle and parse the both the responses from service ?

```
responseMap =  restUtils.findDocuments(urlBuilder.build(),new HashMap<String,List<Map<String,String>>>().getClass());


**RestUtils Class:** 
public <E> E findDocuments(String url,Class<E> targetClass) throws JsonProcessingException {

    MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    headers.add(ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    headers.add(CONTENT_TYPE,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    //headers.add("id", StringUtils.trimToEmpty(policyNo));
    HttpEntity<Object> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(headers);
    ResponseEntity<E> response = restTemplate.exchange(url,HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, targetClass);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonResponse = mapper.writeValueAsString(response); 
    System.out.println(jsonResponse);

    return (E) response.getBody();
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Terrible formating. Please fix it ;)

Comment: Don't know how to format json on SO editor, tried to put in a formatted Json but it make a mess of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Response1(Single Document)**:-

```
{  
 "irpage":[  
  {  
     "drawer":"HPPS",
     "folderNumber":"HPA00008047642",
     "docID":"1",
     "pageNumber":"1",
     "din":"HPPSHPA00008047642000001",
     "userKey1":"20151119NJ",
     "docType":"APPD",
     "docDate":"20151119",
     "numberPages":"1",
     "fileName":"\12_HPPS\20151119\5_Z000\SCHEDL2\952490010845",
     "tempFileName":"\\prcins.net\Shared\irtestnjimages01\12_HPPS\20151119\5_Z000\SCHEDL2\952490010845.pdf",
     "driver":"",
     "dateCaptured":"20151119",
     "timeCaptured":"08:45:04",
     "singleInd":"S",
     "userID":"SCHEDL2",
     "status":"U",
     "batch":"Z000",
     "format":"PDF",
     "media":"D",
     "orientation":"0",
     "tempDin":"12201511190845952490845SCHEDL2",
     "transType":"APPD",
     "operator":"",
     "userkey2":"0",
     "reason":"Computer Generated Document",
     "archiveStatus":"A",
     "archiveDate":"20151119",
     "deviceID":"1",
     "packageID":"1",
     "packageType":"15007",
     "markedInd":"0",
     "dspPageNumber":"1",
     "aMedia":"",
     "aDrive":"",
     "description":"Output",
     "folderName":"GAIL BARTLING",
     "docDescription":"Application Document",
     "overlayID":null,
     "docIndex":null
  }
 ]
}
```

**Response2(Multiple Documents)**

```
{  
 "irpage":[  
  {  
     "drawer":"HPPS",
     "folderNumber":"HPA00008047642",
     "docID":"1",
     "pageNumber":"1",
     "din":"HPPSHPA00008047642000001",
     "userKey1":"20151119NJ",
     "docType":"APPD",
     "docDate":"20151119",
     "numberPages":"1",
     "fileName":"\12_HPPS\20151119\5_Z000\SCHEDL2\952490010845",
     "tempFileName":"\\prcins.net\Shared\irtestnjimages01\12_HPPS\20151119\5_Z000\SCHEDL2\952490010845.pdf",
     "driver":"",
     "dateCaptured":"20151119",
     "timeCaptured":"08:45:04",
     "singleInd":"S",
     "userID":"SCHEDL2",
     "status":"U",
     "batch":"Z000",
     "format":"PDF",
     "media":"D",
     "orientation":"0",
     "tempDin":"12201511190845952490845SCHEDL2",
     "transType":"APPD",
     "operator":"",
     "userkey2":"0",
     "reason":"Computer Generated Document",
     "archiveStatus":"A",
     "archiveDate":"20151119",
     "deviceID":"1",
     "packageID":"1",
     "packageType":"15007",
     "markedInd":"0",
     "dspPageNumber":"1",
     "aMedia":"",
     "aDrive":"",
     "description":"Output",
     "folderName":"GAIL BARTLING",
     "docDescription":"Application Document",
     "overlayID":null,
     "docIndex":null
  },
  {  
     "drawer":"HPPS",
     "folderNumber":"HPA00008047642",
     "docID":"4",
     "pageNumber":"1",
     "din":"HPPSHPA00008047642000004",
     "userKey1":"20160104NJ",
     "docType":"FINA",
     "docDate":"20160104",
     "numberPages":"1",
     "fileName":"\12_HPPS\20160105\5_Z000\SCHEDL2\308070010819",
     "tempFileName":"\\prcins.net\Shared\irtestnjimages01\12_HPPS\20160105\5_Z000\SCHEDL2\308070010819.pdf",
     "driver":"",
     "dateCaptured":"20160105",
     "timeCaptured":"08:19:30",
     "singleInd":"S",
     "userID":"SCHEDL2",
     "status":"U",
     "batch":"Z000",
     "format":"PDF",
     "media":"D",
     "orientation":"0",
     "tempDin":"12201601050819308070819SCHEDL2",
     "transType":"FINA",
     "operator":"",
     "userkey2":"0",
     "reason":"Computer Generated Document",
     "archiveStatus":"A",
     "archiveDate":"20160105",
     "deviceID":"1",
     "packageID":"4",
     "packageType":"15007",
     "markedInd":"0",
     "dspPageNumber":"1",
     "aMedia":"",
     "aDrive":"",
     "description":"Output",
     "folderName":"GAIL BARTLING",
     "docDescription":"Final Notice of Cancellation",
     "overlayID":null,
     "docIndex":null
  }
 ]
}
```

I'd solve it this way

```
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        responseObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyClass.class);
```

MyClass

```
public class MyClass {
    List<ArrayEntry> irpage;

    public class ArrayEntry {
        String drawer;
        String folderNumber;
        ...
    }
}
```

Use modifiers that you need (public/private)

Maven dependency for Gson

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks.